# Differences in Hibernate @OneToMany Output between MariaDB and PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, mariadb

I encountered some interesting behaviour that I'd like someone to help me confirm.
I have running in Docker the latest PostgreSQL and the latest MariaDB containers.
To connect to each one, I am using the latest JDBC drivers available for both databases.

I am using a @OneToMany relationship in two Entities:

```
@Entity
@Data //(lombok)
public class Parent {

  @Id
  @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "uuid")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  UUID id;

  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>()

}
```

```
@Entity
@Data //(lombok)
public class Parent {

  @Id
  @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "uuid")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  UUID id;

  ...

  @JsonIgnore
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
  Parent parent;

}
```

Now the interesting thing is that using the PostgreSQL driver I am able to retrieve the children after persistence. Doing a `parent.getChildren()` will fetch the persisted child entities.

However, using the latest MariaDB driver is a different story. I can confirm in columns for the `child` entities that the foreign key is populated with the UUID of the `parent` - yet doing a `parent.getChildren()` returns an empty array.

Can anyone else confirm these findings - or if there is something that can be done to address said findings?

Comment: the second entity, did you mean `Child` class?

Comment: start the mariadb container with command `--general-log --log-output=TABLE` and after doing your connection `SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log` to see what query was executed.

Comment: @user404 to clarify, when I persist the OneToMany relationship using `parentRepository.save(parent)` the parent and child entities are saved with the right foreign keys.
However, when fetching the parent class and evaluating the `.getChildren()` function the collection is empty only for MariaDB - yet it is populated for PostgreSQL

Comment: @GeoffreyLee, fair enough. case seems a bit unusual. How did you get empty? printing on console or debug pointer or some other ways? Being children lazy type, it needs to be invoked explicitly.  You have to call/execute `.getChildren` explicitly. Another part: enable query printing on app console and see what is the the actual query being fired for that case and execute that separatly in your db.

Comment: MariaDB and MySQL use the repeatable read isolation level by default, whereas PostgreSQL defaults to read committed. This could be the reason for the difference in behavior. Try configuring read committed explicitly.